# how do you change the color of nav bar

Tags: html, css

How would i change the colour of my nav bar in this code?

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
body 
    {
      background-color:#454545;
      color:white;
      font-family:"Courier New";
      text-align:center;
    }
      a:link
    {
      color:white;
    }
      a:visited
    {
      color:white;
    }
      a:hover
    {
      color:white;
    }
      a:active
    {
      color:white;
    }
.nav
    {
      border:1px solid #ccc;
      border-width:1px 0;
      list-style:none;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      text-align:center;
    }
    .nav li{
    display:inline;
    }
.nav a
    {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    }
h1
    {
      font-size:40;
    }
h2
    {
      font-size:27.5;
      text-decoration:underline;
    }
h3
    {
      font-size:20;
    }
p
    {
      font-size:12;
    }
    </style>
```

HTML

```
<li><a href="http://">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://">Youtube</a></li>
<li><a href="https://">Twitter</a></li>
```

I've looked up how to change it but it only gave me things about twitter. I just want to know how to change the  navigation bar colour not the whole page colour.

Comment: can you please post the HTML as well?

Comment: By 'colour' you mean the font-colour (`color`) or the background-colour (`background-color`)? And in what way, precisely, are you stuck with this, given you seem to be aware of CSS (in general, at least)?

Comment: I mean the background-colour of the navigation bar area but not the full page.

Comment: In which case: [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-color).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the background colour of the navigation bar itself, add this to the `.nav` class:

```
background-color:#002d60;
```

You could use something like [colorpicker.com](http://colorpicker.com) to find colour hexadecimal codes.
If you would instead like to change the colour of the text in the navigation bar, add a `color` property like so:

```
color:#003d60;
```

For both of these instances, you could also use `rgba(n,n,n,n)`, `rgb(n,n,n)` or even `hsl(n,n,n)` to select colours with red-green-blue or hue-saturation-lightness values.

Answer (score 0):

Add a background to the `.nav` block?

```
background: #FFDD00; //some color
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this is the right section of css to colorize some element.

```
background-color:#000;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell without seeing all the code or the desired effect, but background-color is the CSS property you want for changing the background, or color for changing the text color.